# Make a Crystal Report selective over the data that it shows

Tags: vb.net, select, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have many reports in a project, each showing different data about different things. I have shown the user the project, and his main feedback was this:

> I like the reports, however I notice that in a lot of them, the tables show all of the columns that meet the report criteria (what the report is showing), even if they are empty. Can you change them so that if a column is empty, it is not displayed, as this takes up needless space?

Is there a way I can achieve this? For example, if the report is `Sales by Customer x by Suppliers`, and one supplier has no data for this customer, I don't want that supplier to be shown. Is there a way I can get the report to only display columns if they contain data?

To clarify, the effect I am after is, if the report below was shown, the column `Arris Rail (144) 75x75 1.282m` would not be displayed.

[image]

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Comment: @Siva we've re-structured the reports in a different way now, the user gave us a new layout to use so we've not got crosstabs anymore

Answer (score 0):

Right click on crostab > Cross-tab expert > customise style

set option `Suppres empty columns`

I think you need to replace "-" value to null or empty

Comment: Hi Mat, where do I replace "-" with null/empty? In the code or report?

Comment: Hi, i see that the values presented in crosstab are not numbers so you should replace theme in the code.

Comment: Or if not, you can try to change properties for value field: rightlick on the field > format field > tab Numbers

Comment: Just doing the supressing with the Crosstab Expert has worked, so thank you. Shouldn't need the replacement

Comment: My mistake, this actually hasn't solved the issue. Because of the sub-columns having values (Arris Rail, Gravel Boards, etc), it determines them as full columns, so doesn't get rid of them. It only gets rid of the columns if there are no sub-columns either

Comment: The option i suggested should suppres column Arris Rail (144) 75x75 1.828 m. Is it works differently?

Comment: When suppressing the empty rows/columns on the same report, it hides all of the rows except for June 2016, July 2016, and Total

Comment: And all column are still visible?

Comment: If column names are not group fields but values, only way to hide "empty" columns is to remove them from data source